# The actions created by me are blocked in the Ribbon, after the close "Customize" window, why does this happen?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, ribbon

I use the component in Delphi XE2 TRibbon, I have a problem, when I open the "Customize" window to add new actions to the "RibbonQuickAccessToolbar". When I close the window; ActionManager actions in which they were created by me, are blocked in the Ribbon. Why does this happen?

dfm:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 452
  ClientWidth = 806
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Ribbon1: TRibbon
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 806
    Height = 143
    ActionManager = ActionManager1
    Caption = 'Ribbon1'
    QuickAccessToolbar.ActionBar = RibbonQuickAccessToolbar1
    Tabs = <
      item
        Caption = 'RibbonPage1'
        Page = RibbonPage1
      end
      item
        Caption = 'RibbonPage2'
        Page = RibbonPage2
      end>
    TabIndex = 1
    ExplicitLeft = 400
    ExplicitTop = 176
    ExplicitWidth = 0
    DesignSize = (
      806
      143)
    StyleName = 'Ribbon - Luna'
    object RibbonPage1: TRibbonPage
      Left = 0
      Top = 50
      Width = 805
      Height = 93
      Caption = 'RibbonPage1'
      Index = 0
      object RibbonGroup1: TRibbonGroup
        Left = 4
        Top = 3
        Width = 53
        Height = 86
        ActionManager = ActionManager1
        Caption = 'RibbonGroup1'
        GroupIndex = 0
      end
      object RibbonGroup2: TRibbonGroup
        Left = 59
        Top = 3
        Width = 53
        Height = 86
        ActionManager = ActionManager1
        Caption = 'RibbonGroup2'
        GroupIndex = 1
      end
    end
    object RibbonQuickAccessToolbar1: TRibbonQuickAccessToolbar
      Left = 49
      Top = 1
      Width = 48
      Height = 24
      ActionManager = ActionManager1
    end
    object RibbonPage2: TRibbonPage
      Left = 0
      Top = 50
      Width = 805
      Height = 93
      Caption = 'RibbonPage2'
      Index = 1
      object RibbonGroup3: TRibbonGroup
        Left = 4
        Top = 3
        Width = 53
        Height = 86
        ActionManager = ActionManager1
        Caption = 'RibbonGroup3'
        GroupIndex = 0
      end
      object RibbonGroup4: TRibbonGroup
        Left = 59
        Top = 3
        Width = 53
        Height = 86
        ActionManager = ActionManager1
        Caption = 'RibbonGroup4'
        GroupIndex = 1
      end
    end
  end
  object ActionManager1: TActionManager
    ActionBars = <
      item
        Items = <
          item
            Action = Action1
            Caption = '&Action1'
          end
          item
            Action = Action2
            Caption = 'A&ction2'
          end>
        ActionBar = RibbonGroup1
      end
      item
        Items = <
          item
            Action = Action3
            Caption = '&Action3'
          end
          item
            Action = Action4
            Caption = 'A&ction4'
          end>
        ActionBar = RibbonGroup2
      end
      item
        Items = <
          item
            Action = Action5
            Caption = '&Action5'
          end
          item
            Action = Action6
            Caption = 'A&ction6'
          end>
        ActionBar = RibbonGroup3
      end
      item
        Items = <
          item
            Action = Action7
            Caption = '&Action7'
          end
          item
            Action = Action8
            Caption = 'A&ction8'
          end>
        ActionBar = RibbonGroup4
      end
      item
        ActionBar = RibbonQuickAccessToolbar1
        AutoSize = False
      end>
    Left = 496
    Top = 224
    StyleName = 'Ribbon - Luna'
    object Action1: TAction
      Caption = 'Action1'
      OnExecute = Action1Execute
    end
    object Action2: TAction
      Caption = 'Action2'
      OnExecute = Action1Execute
    end
    object Action3: TAction
      Caption = 'Action3'
      OnExecute = Action1Execute
    end
    object Action4: TAction
      Caption = 'Action4'
      OnExecute = Action1Execute
    end
    object Action5: TAction
      Caption = 'Action5'
      OnExecute = Action1Execute
    end
    object Action6: TAction
      Caption = 'Action6'
      OnExecute = Action1Execute
    end
    object Action7: TAction
      Caption = 'Action7'
      OnExecute = Action1Execute
    end
    object Action8: TAction
      Caption = 'Action8'
      OnExecute = Action1Execute
    end
  end
end
```

pas:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ActnList, Vcl.ActnMan, Vcl.ToolWin,
  Vcl.ActnCtrls, Vcl.Ribbon, Vcl.RibbonLunaStyleActnCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Ribbon1: TRibbon;
    RibbonPage1: TRibbonPage;
    RibbonGroup1: TRibbonGroup;
    RibbonPage2: TRibbonPage;
    ActionManager1: TActionManager;
    Action1: TAction;
    Action2: TAction;
    Action3: TAction;
    Action4: TAction;
    Action5: TAction;
    Action6: TAction;
    Action7: TAction;
    Action8: TAction;
    RibbonGroup2: TRibbonGroup;
    RibbonGroup3: TRibbonGroup;
    RibbonGroup4: TRibbonGroup;
    RibbonQuickAccessToolbar1: TRibbonQuickAccessToolbar;
    procedure Action1Execute(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Action1Execute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Hello world!');
end;

end.
```

Comment: What does "blocked in the Ribbon" mean? Do you mean "disabled"?

Comment: I just tried your sample code, and it works fine. I followed the same instructions I gave you below (in reverse) to move the code from here to a new, empty Delphi app. I ran it, added your `Action2` to the Quick Access Bar by dragging, and then closed the Customize dialog and clicked the action. I got the "Hello world!" message. I then changed the code to change the ShowMessage to `'Hello world! You clicked ' + TAction(Sender).Caption);`, and did the same again. I got the message "Hello world! You clicked Action2" instead. So both times the action added worked fine, and that was **your code**.

Comment: Um .. that problem is not the truth may be happening, this baffles me even more. Thanks Ken, Best Regards

Comment: Hi Ken, you tested my code? which may be causing this error?. 
I did a quick example on my home computer I installed the Delphi 2010 and the same problem occurs. In my work I have installed delphi xe2 and the same error occurs.

Comment: As I said in my last comment, "I just tried your sample code", and it works fine. Read what I wrote again.

Comment: Which version of delphi use your? because I've tried everything and still gives this error, even on different computers

Answer (score 0):

Actions are automatically disabled if they have no event handler assigned for the `OnExecute` event. This is true whether it's in the Ribbon's Quick Access Bar, a `TActionToolBar` or `TActionMainMenuBar`, or a standard `TButton with an Action assigned to its`Action` property. (They're disabled by default with no OnExecute handler assigned because without one there's nothing for it to do if it were Enabled and the user selected it.)

Standard actions usually have a default `OnExecute` handler assigned internally. For instance, a `TEditCopy` action automatically enables/disables itself based on whether there is text selected to copy to the clipboard.

To enable your own actions, make sure you have a handler assigned for the [TAction.OnExecute](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE6/en/TActionOnUpdate_%28Delphi%29) event. You can change whether it's enabled or disabled using the `TAction.OnUpdate` event handler at runtime. For instance, to enable the `DeleteRecord` action only if the database field 'Processed' is false, you could use:

```
procedure TForm1.actDeleteRecordUpdate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  (Sender as TAction).Enabled := not OrderDataProcessed.AsBoolean;
end;
```

Note that OnUpdate is called very often, every time the application is idle. This means that any code you put there should execute *very quickly*, as it is called very frequently; if you put code in there that takes a long time to run, it will drastically show down the user interface of your application and increase CPU use.

Comment: My own actions, they have assigned the event OnExecute

Comment: Sorry. You'll need to edit your question (as I've asked before) to provide enough information to allow us to reproduce the problem. I can do a quick test app that works fine for me, and the Ribbon Demo that comes with Delphi works fine if you customize the Quick Access Bar to add actions as well. So it's something in your code that's causing the issue, and you've not given enough information for us to use to find out what is doing so.

Comment: The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE6/en/TActionOnUpdate_%28Delphi%29) shows how to use OnUpdate. To enable/disable, use `(Sender as TAction).Enabled := WhatEver_Condition_Enables_Your_Action;`. For instance, an action to allow the user to delete a database row only if it hasn't been processed yet might be `(Sender as TAction).Enabled := not DataSetProcessed.AsBoolean;`.

Comment: Try to make your application quick test and see if the above occurs. 

Thanks, I await your response soon. 

Best regards Ken

Comment: Um, no. **It's not my job to reproduce your problem**. I'm not the one asking for help. **You** create the "application quick test**. You're the one asking for our help, and it's the problem you're having that needs to be solved. **You** do the work to show us the problem so we can help you, and [edit] your question to include it (as I've asked you to [edit] it before and you still have not).

Comment: Here I made my example and the same problem occurs: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72467567/Ejemplo.zip

Comment: @Jerry: In case it's not clear: All of the information for your question belongs **here, in your question**, so that it's useful to others in the future. *Here* is not a Dropbox somewhere; it's here in your question. Once again, please [edit] your question to include the details here where it belongs. I've asked several times now for you to do so, and provided clickable links in order to make it easy to [edit] your question. Thanks.

Comment: I just edit the question sorry I'm not very good with English but I am learning

Comment: @Jerry: No, that is not including the code here; that's just including the link here. *Post the code here.* Right-click your form in your sample application and hit Alt+F12 to View as Text, then Ctrl+A, then Ctrl+C, and paste that into your question with Ctrl+V, then Ctrl+K to format as code. Add a couple of blank lines. Switch back to Delphi, Alt+F12 again to switch back to form view, F12 to switch to Code Editor. Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C to copy; back to StackOverflow, Ctrl+V to paste, Ctrl+K to format. Once you've done that, I'll clean up any formatting that is needed.

Comment: There is an example with Delphi that shows how your own actions should work. It's in the Samples folder, as "Ribbon Controls\ApplicationMenu". Run it, click the Quick Access Toolbar icon to customize, and drag the "Do Not Forward" Close action to the Quick Access ToolBar. It is enabled. Click it, and you see the text "Executed: PermissionDoNotForward" appear in the memo area of the form. Find that Action in the Structure window (top left), and then switch the Object Inspector to the Events tab. Double-click the `OnExecute` event to go to the code that it executes.

Comment: Run the demo but the same problem occurs. Closing the More Commands Customize window, custom actions are disabled. 
Test run my example code.